# How can I fix The index was out of range error?

Tags: c#, list, indexing, datatable, datarow

I developed a piece of code allowing to cut the values ​​of a cell in excel by putting a value by rowand I had the following error:

"The index was out of range. It must not be negative and must be less than the size of the parameter name: index"

```
private DataTable trasnformDT(DataTable dt1)
    {
        DataTable dt = dt1.Clone();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
        {
            List<string> Word_countLst = row["Word_count"].ToString().Trim().TrimStart('[').TrimEnd(']').Split(',').ToList();
            List<string> command_addressLst = row["command_address"].ToString().Trim().TrimStart('[').TrimEnd(']').Split(',').ToList();
            List<string> response_addressLst = row["response_address"].ToString().Trim().TrimStart('[').TrimEnd(']').Split(',').ToList();

            string[] Register_numberLst = row["Register_number"].ToString().Trim().TrimStart('[').TrimEnd(']').Split(',');
            string[] Register_valueLst = row["Register_value"].ToString().Trim().TrimStart('[').TrimEnd(']').Split(',');

            if (row["Word_count"].ToString().Trim() == "[]")
            {

                if (command_addressLst.Count() == response_addressLst.Count())
                {
                    int j = 0;
                    foreach (string item in command_addressLst)
                    {
                        //    long cacount = Int64.Parse(item);

                        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                        dr.ItemArray = row.ItemArray;
                        dr["command_address"] = command_addressLst[j];
                        dr["response_address"] = response_addressLst[j];
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                        j++;
                    }
                }

            }

            else

                {
                   foreach (string item in Word_countLst)
                    foreach (string item2 in command_addressLst)
                    {
                            long wcount = Int64.Parse(item);
                            long wcount2 = Int64.Parse(item2);
                            for (int j = 0; j < wcount; j++)
                            {
                                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                                dr.ItemArray = row.ItemArray;
                                dr["Word_count"] = item;
                                dr["Register_number"] = Register_numberLst[j];
                                dr["Register_value"] = Register_valueLst[j];
                                dr["command_address"] = item2;
                                dr["response_address"] = item2;
                            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                            }

                        }
                }


            i++;
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

I want to split word_count, register_value and register_number as it mentionned but and for command_address and command_response split them as like for word_count but for another lenght. But this code split doubly

Comment: Make sure the length of **command_addressLst** and **response_addressLst** match. Same thing for **Register_numberLst** and **Register_valueLst**

Comment: @PaulSütterlin:  Yes you are right command_addressLst and response_addressLst dont have the same length.

Comment: @PaulSütterlin: Hw can I modify the previous code. I modified the initial post

Comment: If the two lists length cannot differ from each other, your Excel file is probably broken, else you have to use two different loops to split the lists. You cannot use the same index for two lists if they dont have the same length. The index can be bigger than one of your arrays. If that happens this error is thrown.

Comment: I would use two foreach loops to avoid this error